# Split or Replace - get rid of apostrophes and comma between and around two strings

Tags: python, printing, replace, split, python-2.x

I have `print(x,y)` at the end of my program. Where x equals alpha- and y equals zeta. I want the end result to print out `(alpha-zeta)`, but instead it prints out `('alpha-', 'zeta')`. I've tried using the strip and replace commands, but have been unsuccessful in my efforts. Can someone help me with this seemingly simple task?

Comment: Write ``print "(%s-%s)' % (x,y)`` if you want parentheses and ``print "%s-%s' % (x,y)`` if you want no parentheses. See (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Answer (score 1):

Just concat the two strings:

```
print x + y
```

As you are using Python 2, the parentheses are actually not part of the `print` and thus might affect your result. In your case, you had two values separated by a comma inside the parentheses which created a tuple. This is essentially what happened there:

```
t = (x, y)
print t
```

As such, you printed the representation of the tuple instead of the values `x` and `y` separately.